# Sliver of tire wall coming off

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

I parked my car today and noticed that part of the tire wall is coming off. I’m a very cautious person, and so when I seen this I immediately freaked out. I was wondering if I should get a new tire, or should I be ok with driving with this damage?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the “rib” provided to protect the alloy rim - it is safe to continue to drive on it - as long as that was done at low speed ie parking speed...

Comment: Unless, perhaps you have been parking like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3BGkOKVMUU